# Usage of above as adverb

Tags: adverbs

I know that adverbs modify adjectives, verbs and other adverbs but, this usage of the "above" as adverb is so different from the definiton of the adverb in english.

> the clouds above
>
> except as stated above
>
> 10 degrees above

The dictionary page ı took my examples: [Link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/above)

Comment: In modern grammar, "above" is classed as a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ Even if it is, it is still confusing because the preposition is at the end

Comment: Prepositions frequently occur a the end of a clause., for example, "That depends on who I give it **to**"./ "What did you hit me **for**?"

Comment: above can be a preposition **OR** an adverb. See Merriam Webster. 10 degrees above [zero]. Yes, a preposition. And Cambridge: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/above

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Similar to 'here',indicating a kind of orientation.And also,'here' has some usage like yours:**My friend here** will show you the way.(the clouds above),I've **lived here **for about two years.(except as stated above)

Comment: Above the clouds=preposition; the clouds above=adverb [where the clouds are]

Comment: Regarding the word *preposition* It would be more correct to call the class of words something else e.g. *adposition*, but the term *preposition* seems deeply ingrained in English grammar. Similarly, I've seen "ago" called a *preposition* even though it's strictly a *postposition* as it always comes after a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Modern grammar classifies "above" as a preposition.

One reason is that it occurs where PPs typically occur:

Compare:

> *This goes in the closet*. ~ *This goes above*.
>
> *Put it underneath the sink*. ~  *Put it above*.
>
> *In the room, there was nothing*. ~ *Above, there was nothing*.
>
> *I want it right underneath.* ~ *I want it right above*.

Those examples show that there are strong reasons for saying that "above" belongs to the class of prepositions, not the class of adverb (or adjective).

Comment: And to be clear,  in this modern understanding, prepositions need not have what classically would be called objects (Above **what**?). That explains why *the road ahead* is fine while something like \**the road to* isn’t.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum It impoverishes English to claim all aboves are prepositions. What does one gain from that? And most dictionaries disagree with this anyway.

Comment: @Lambie Sometimes ı feel like understanding is enough, dont try to define it. :D

Comment: @Lambie, don’t shoot the messenger. I will say that there are very strong arguments to the effect that the traditional approach is woefully inadequate. For a presentation of some of these arguments—and a harsh critique of most dictionaries in this regard—see [a paper by Pullum](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ZAA_final_proof.pdf) to which I was recently turned on over at [English Language & Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611449/has-the-conception-of-prepositions-broadened).

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I try and stay away from Pullum. A mere reading of the dict. entries shows the adverb and prep. work differently.

Comment: @Lambie, as you wish. I offered the reference merely in response to your question, “What does one gain from [calling them prepositions]?”

Comment: But adverbs also occur where PPs typically occur: "This goes here." "Put it here." "Here, there was nothing." (Or are you arguing that "here" is a preposition, too?)

Comment: As a matter of fact, @MarcInManhattan, yes, in the modern analysis *here* is a preposition. Consider *The air **here** is humid*. It’s like *The air **in Havana** is humid* and unlike \**The air **extremely** is humid*.

Comment: @Paul Tanenbaum But, you replace 'here'  to 'in Havana'(a prep phrase).In merriam-webster,I find it uses prep phrases to describe a adverb.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum That seems strange to me because, while I know of prepositions that may omit objects (complements), I'm not aware of any that may never have objects. (I suppose that there must be several such always objectless "prepositions" in H&P.) Furthermore, both "here" and "in Havana" seem to function adjectivally in those sentences (explaining why "extremely" doesn't work there). But if that's how H&P parse it, then OK.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, locative "here" is best classified as a preposition, an intransitive one of course since it is a one-word phrase.  Compare: "Put it here" ~ "Put it in this place". And "This goes here" ~ "This goes in this place".

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum "Modern grammar classifies "above" as a preposition" It's preposition at times, but not always.

Comment: It's always a preposition, as I explained in my answer.